# Why does webform configuration not let me choose existing content types

Tags: webforms

I've installed the `Webform` module and would like it to configure so that I can add a form to a `Basic page` content. But `/admin/config/content/webform` does not let me specify any content types. Where is that setting hidden?
Thanks!

**EDIT1**
What I'm seeing:[image]---------------------------

What I would expect to see:[image]

Why don't I get the choice of the existing content types??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admin Menu --> Structure --> Content Types --> Basic Page's Edit --> Webform tab --> select Enable

I not sure is this what you mean.